# Outlook 2016: Font color for inline answer

Tags: colors, microsoft-outlook-2016

For some emails it is useful to reply within the original message text itself ("inline answer"). This requires that there are e.g. font color differences to see who wrote what.

In Outlook 2010, I used the Options ribbon: the second button is labelled 'Colors' (in the Themes tab). I added a few colors and was happy for years.

Now I am using Outlook 2016. The 'Colors' button is there but does nothing I could notice.

Which strategy is the most efficient for color-per-author inline answers?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly, you may consider changing the reply font color under File > Options > Mail > Stationary and Fonts, click Font button for "Replying or forwarding messages".
[image]
Also, enable the "Preface comments with" option under File > Options > Mail > Replies and forwards:
[image]